# how to create mysql database from sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a database from MySQL query. I have used the following, but it is not working.

```
$sql2 = "CREATE DATABASE DATABAE_NAME";
$query2=mysqli_query($connect_dude,$sql2);
```

This query is not creating any database. Probably,I have to use database username and password, but I'm not quite sure how to apply or use database username, password and host in this case.

Comment: You are neither verifying whether `mysqli_query()` succeeds nor retrieving the error message if any.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I verified that and it's giving me failure msg

Comment: msg says database not created

Comment: Make sure you're connected and that you have permissions to create a database. Check your PHPmyadmin's settings.

Comment: I'm connected for sure.But i don't know how to check the permission to create database.any clue?

Comment: http://webvaultwiki.com.au/(S(iungfwenvz2f5c55pioeinil))/Create-Mysql-Database-User-Phpmyadmin.ashx

Comment: GRANT create db to your user

Comment: You'd need to check with your host to see if permissions are granted to create a DB outside of the control panel.

Comment: @Fred-ii-if i test it in localhost,will it work?

Comment: Probably, try it out and see.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is working in localhost.I'll contact my hosting provider about this issue.Thanks for your support and time

Comment: You're very much welcome Salim, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample php code about connecting DB
Hope this will help.

```
<?php

//mysqli query for connecting database  
//mysqli_connect('host','username','password')
$connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
if($connection)
{
    //saving query for creating database in a variable 
    $query="CREATE DATABASE student";

    //creating Database
    $newdb=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    //testing whether database created or not 

    if($newdb)
    {
        //setting database name to connect for database operation
        $setDbName="student";

        //query for connecting database
        $connectionTesing=mysqli_select_db($connection,$setDbName);

        if($connectionTesing)
        {
            echo "Connected!";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I already fixed the problem.But I'm talking your one as the solution.Thanks